# Blank page with JSON errors after build in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, vue.js, build

I was build my first project (i trying to learn some about vue.js) and when i use npm run build i getting blank pages with errors about JSON. But when i use typical npm run serve, this page looks cool and working at all..

I tried to include JSON file in router.js in "components" and still not working.

```
import articlejson from '@/components/databases/article.json';

export default {
    name: 'index',
    methods: {}
}
function getArticles() {
    for(let i=0; i<articlejson.length; i++) {
        const articlestructure = '<a href="/articles/' + articlejson[i].id + '"><div class="kk-activeblock row"><div class="image col-md-3" style="background-image:url(' + articlejson[i].imageURL + ')"></div><div class="col-md-9"><div class="title">' + articlejson[i].title + '</div><div class="desc">' + articlejson[i].description + '</div><div class="tags"><div class="badge" type="' + articlejson[i].tags.first + '"></div><divclass="badge" type="' + articlejson[i].tags.two + '"></div></div></div></div>'
        $('#activity-section').append(articlestructure)
    }
}
```

I think this is problem with generating normal site. Actually, in my 'div id app' is only a comment. Why i think this is wrong with JSON? beacuse console show me:  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at HTMLDocument. (Articles.vue:41) at l (jquery.js:3557) at c (jquery.js:3625)**

Answer (score 0):

`articlejson` is undefined. So your import is failing, the loading of `article.json` fails I guess.

Without knowing the complete setup I would guess you didn't setup [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or something similar?

Comment: I need just to put in articles.vue module.exports and include .json files?

Comment: You need to provide more infos. What does the `serve` and `build` command do? Did you use the `vue create`? Or is your project setup done on your own? What is the output of your debug console?

Comment: I use vue ui and create project with UI from Vue.js. serve just start server without errors. The same about build. I dont get any errors in console after ```npm run build``` but when i trying to start index.html i just got blank page.